# How to keep track of account balance updates

Tags: transactions

I'm looking for a method that tells me about the receive transactions on my account/address from node. I got the balance of addresses from node by `getBalance()` method, but i want to get the transactions that are received on my address.

I only have records of transactions that i have sent from my account through `sendTransaction(fromAccount, toAccount, lamports)` method, and it returns a **tx_hash**. So i can keep record of send transactions in my database by **tx_hash**.

But if i receive some amount on my address, how can i get that transaction(s)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`onAccountChange`](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#onAccountChange):

```
const connection = new Connection("<some rpc provider>");
connection.onAccountChange(accountToMonitor, async () => {
      const currentSigs = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(accountToMonitor);
      const currentTxs = await connection.getTransactions(currentSigs);
      // Check in your database if all transactions are included
      // and add the new ones you'd like to include.
});
```

Comment: Small warning though: In my personal experience this can be a little slow, so if speed is critical here you might want to look for a third party web hook provider on Solana

Comment: There are too much accounts/addresses, and they will keep increasing with time.
How can i keep track of all accounts.
Just i want the transactions that are received on my addresses.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but the main idea is the same. You have a webhook like in my answer for each address you want to track. How you do this at scale is an architecture question and probably can't be easily answered without more information about the type of system you're building

Comment: ok 
Can you please tell how solscan keep track of all transactions ?

Comment: I don't know this as I don't work for them. I would assume with a similar method as I described and a big database, but I'm no expert on the matter. Wouldn't be surprised if they run their own validators too to make use of all this data, but I'm only guessing.