# How can I listen to a change in ATA's balance for multiple accounts in my database?

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, rpc, websocket, webhook

How can I listen to a change in ATA's balance for multiple accounts in my database? I am trying to listen to all solana addresses and their ATA's  to check for a change in their balance when a user sends tokens to them.

Comment: You can register a listener to the ATA using `@solana/web3.js` library - https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#onAccountChange

Comment: Feel free to put this as an answer and not as a comment, because it's correct!

Comment: This is a duplicate from https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5554/how-to-keep-track-of-account-balance-updates/5559#5559

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep track of account balance updates](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5554/how-to-keep-track-of-account-balance-updates)